# Image not showing in HTML5&CSS

Tags: css, html

I've been looking around for the past two hours for a solution. I'm currently learning HTML5&CSS just for fun, I'm just Visual Studios IDE because it works great. You can create HTML5 pages etc in it. Now, here's the problem.

I want a background picture, but it's not showing up. I've tried putting borders around it(and the borders shows up around the "picture" that's suppose to show.) The code is "right", but I can't get it to work. Please help.

In the head, style type="text/css".

```
        #imageonly {
        background-image: url(C:\Users\user\Documents\random.png);
        height: 100px;
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

In the body.

```
    <div id="imageonly">
</div>
```

If you need anything more, just ask. Sorry if anyone gets annoyed etc. I'm just really confused. Regards Rob.

Comment: I forgot, you maybe wanna see how it looks like. This is how it looks like in the Visual Studios:  https://gyazo.com/6d5b74931d2ff96d2807bf57dc49dbf2. But when I run it in any browser(I.E, Firefox, Chrome). It shows now picture, it's just blank.

Comment: Do your self a favor and use Developer Tools in Chrome (Firefox...)... hit F12 and see in console if you have any errors. Most probably your path is wrong.

Comment: Try accessing the `png` image from the browser.

Comment: use a relative path for your image url, not the absolute path on your local disk

Comment: Your image should be within accessible scope of HTML. Try giving relative path, with respect to HTML file

Comment: Nevermind, thanks you for all your answers. It works now! I really appreciate it. I changed the location of the picture to the same folder where my .html file was located at. Thanks you once again.

Comment: @RobinA.Yes. create an `images` folder in the root of your project and then right click the folder in Visual Studio, click "Add Exsisting..." and select your `random.png`. Then update you CSS `background-image` to `background-image: url(images/random.png);`

Comment: @RobinA.All your web project assets (css, javascript, images) should always be relative to your projects root since web projects are "portable"

Comment: Alright, I see.. Thanks for the tips, now I can continue with my ongoing "site". Is there a way to make the topic "answered"? Or do you just leave it?

Comment: @RobinA.I can create an answer for it and you can accept it to help other people in the future.

Answer (score 0):

All the assets (css, javascript, images, fonts, etc.) you use for your web project should be relative to the root of your web project, not an absolute path on your local disk.

For your case, create an images folder in your projects root then move the `random.png` to that folder and update your CSS style to this:

`background-image: url(images/random.png);`